# When I use simple adapter,why the listview doesn't appear every time?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I got String **t** as a Json from the web and parsed it.Then I use a SimpleAdapter to add the datas I get to the ListView.But when the program run,I met the problem that the listView sometime disappear and sometime appear successfully.Why is that happened?

```
private void parseData(String t){
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(t);
                        JSONArray datas = (JSONArray)jsonObject.getJSONArray("datas");
                        HashMap<String, String> item;
                        for(int i = 0;i<datas.length();i++){
                            JSONObject info = (JSONObject)datas.getJSONObject(i);
                            String number = info.getString("number");
                            String stocktakingTime = info.getString("stocktakingTime");
                            JSONObject category = info.getJSONObject("category");
                            String text = category.getString("text");
                                item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                item.put("number", number);
                                item.put("stocktakingTime", stocktakingTime);
                                item.put("text",text);  
                                goodsList.add(item);
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }       


public void initWidget() {
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, goodsList,
            R.layout.check_task_list_view, new String[] {
                    "number", "stocktakingTime", "text" },
            new int[] { R.id.checkNumber, R.id.stocktakingTime,
                    R.id.checkText});
    listView = new ListView(this);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent it = new Intent(CheckTaskActivity.this,CheckTaskCustomSellerActivity.class);
                startActivity(it);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent it1 = new Intent(CheckTaskActivity.this,CheckTaskCustomSellerActivity.class);
                startActivity(it1);
                break;


            default:
                break;
            }

        }

    });

    LinearLayout checkTaskList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.checkTaskList);
    checkTaskList.addView(listView);
    bindListener();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where you find "goodsList" variable? it is list variable that create form 
Hash map `(List<? extends Map<String, ?>> item )`

then you make a mistake
the below code

```
for(int i = 0;i<datas.length();i++){
                        JSONObject info = (JSONObject)datas.getJSONObject(i);
                        String number = info.getString("number");
                        String stocktakingTime = info.getString("stocktakingTime");
                        JSONObject category = info.getJSONObject("category");
                        String text = category.getString("text");
                            item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            item.put("number", number);
                            item.put("stocktakingTime", stocktakingTime);
                            item.put("text",text);  
                            goodsList.add(item);
                    }
```

you initialize item variable every time when the for loop running 
then only one item can contain the hasmap.

do it .....................

```
HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        for(int i = 0;i<datas.length();i++){
                            JSONObject info = (JSONObject)datas.getJSONObject(i);
                            String number = info.getString("number");
                            String stocktakingTime = info.getString("stocktakingTime");
                            JSONObject category = info.getJSONObject("category");
                            String text = category.getString("text");

                                item.put("number", number);
                                item.put("stocktakingTime", stocktakingTime);
                                item.put("text",text);  
                                goodsList.add(item);
                        }
```

Comment: I have tried the solution and now I create a HashMap every time, but the problem still exists.

Comment: The possible thinks can be hapend 1. Check the parse data before create adapter . log.d("data", t) when there are no data then list view show no item. 2    . check json key pair value ex. "number" and other key should be match json key other which it show exception.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible the JSONArray datas Empty so you couldn't fill goodsList and then listview doesn't have items so please check datas JSONArray

Comment: To test this problem,I have tested the program and the program gets json data every time including the listview disappear one.